# Xcode Building from non-existant Project File

Tags: iphone, xcode

I'm building my project and I get a build error from within a file that is not part of my project. The file is not listed in the project navigator or in compile sources under build phases.

I've cleaned and run many times, same result.

How do I remove this file?

Comment: What's the file and what's the error? Also, are sure you are looking at the build phases for a target that you are actually building?

Comment: The project only has one target, the error is that a certain .h file is missing.

Comment: Does the whatever.h file have a corresponding whatever.m in the project?

Comment: I suppose, the project is building in an .m file that it shouldn't, which leads it down a path it shouldn't. Some of those files down that path are important to the project and are included (correctly so) in the project.

Comment: So it builds a whatever.m file, which has `#import whatever.h` at the top, so you get a "whatever.h" is missing right? Is the file that is missing something you wrote yourself or is it something that you've never even seen before?

Comment: The file still may be stuck in the compile sources under build phases in the target. Did you check there?

Comment: the file being built incorrectly is something I wrote.

Comment: And then you deleted it right? Did you delete it in Finder or in Xcode?

Comment: Can't delete the file, it's need in many other projects ( I'd prefer to find the reference to the file in the project in question and delete it).

Comment: So the file isn't in the project's folder? Maybe you have a target dependency then? Target depending on a target that depends on that file? No way you could archive the project and upload it somewhere I suppose, right?

Comment: Ok then, if no target dependencies then look in the build phases again, maybe scroll down the list there (lion doesn't show scrollbars, that happened to me one time). That's what determines what gets compiled, so yeah, your only bet is to look in there.

Comment: It it's not then run a project search for "#import whatever.h", maybe something imports it and the problem is not even in the "whatever.m" file

Comment: please add your "whatever.h" file as an answer and I'll accept. A file was imported that contained the "problem.h" file. I searched for problem.h and found nothing. But whatever.h contained problem.h and correct.h shouldn't have had a whatever.h import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the header file, not in the implementation file, something in your code imports that header, remove that statement.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me too. The fix for me was simply to restart XCode.

I think the issue came from me renaming the class and XCode must've cached the old name.